# Issue with req.body.data in Cloud Function after Deployment on Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm encountering an issue with my Google Cloud Function written in TypeScript and called from a Flutter app. The function processes orders and updates Firestore documents. Locally, everything works perfectly when tested with the Firebase emulator, but after deploying to Google Cloud, I face a problem: the function seems unable to read parameters from `req.body.data`.

**Environment:**

- Language: TypeScript for Cloud Function, Dart (Flutter) for client-side
- Google Cloud Function region: europe-west1
- Firebase SDK: firebase-functions/v2 and firebase-admin

**Problem Description:**
When I call the cloud function from my Flutter app, it's supposed to receive order data and update Firestore accordingly. This works as expected when running locally using the Firebase emulator. However, once deployed on Google Cloud, the function fails to read the parameters from `req.body.data`. In the Google Cloud console logs, I see errors indicating that `req.body.data` is undefined or not accessible.

**Code Snippet (TypeScript Cloud Function):**

```js
import {logger, setGlobalOptions} from "firebase-functions/v2";
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin/app";
import {getFirestore, FieldValue} from "firebase-admin/firestore";

setGlobalOptions({region: "europe-west1"});

initializeApp();

interface Order {
  categoryIndex: number;
  plateIndex: number;
  timestamp: number;
  count: number;
  status: number;
}

exports.processOrder = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {areaID, tableID, orders, restaurantID} = req.body.data;

    // Process each user's orders
    for (const userId of Object.keys(orders)) {
      orders[userId] = orders[userId].filter((order: Order) => {
        // Remove order if count is 0 or less
        if (order.count <= 0) {
          return false;
        }

        // Set status to 0 if not already 0
        if (order.status !== 0) {
          order.status = 0;
        }

        return true;
      });
    }

    // Firestore document reference
    const docPath = `restaurants/${restaurantID}/areas/${areaID}` +
                `/tables/${tableID}`;
    const docRef = getFirestore().doc(docPath);

    for (const userId of Object.keys(orders)) {
      await docRef.update({
        [`confirmedOrders.${userId}`]: FieldValue.arrayUnion(...orders[userId]),
      });
    }

    // set the pendingOrders field to empty map
    await docRef.update({
      pendingOrders: {},
    });

    // Success response
    res.send({
      "data": "Order processed successfully",
      "status": true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      logger.error("Error processing order: ", error);
      res.send({
        "data": "Error processing order",
        "status": false,
      });
      res.send({success: false, error: error.message});
    } else {
      logger.error("Unexpected error type");
      res.send({
        "data": "Unexpected error type",
        "status": false,
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Code Snippet (Flutter Client-Side):

```
class FirebaseFunctionsClass {
  FirebaseFunctions functionInstance =
      FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west1');

  // IF YOU WANT TO USE THE LOCAL EMULATOR, UNCOMMENT THIS
  // FirebaseFunctionsClass() {
  //   functionInstance.useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);
  // }

  Future<HttpsCallableResult> processOrder(
      {required String restaurantId,
      required String areaId,
      required String tableId,
      required Map orders}) async {
    try {
      final result = await functionInstance.httpsCallable('processOrder').call({
        'restaurantID': restaurantId,
        'areaID': areaId,
        'tableID': tableId,
        'orders': orders,
      });
      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error calling cloud function: $e");
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Attempts to Resolve:

Verified that the request body format is correct in the Flutter app.
Checked the Cloud Function logs for any errors or warnings.
Ensured that the function and client are using the same region.
Question:
What could be causing this discrepancy between the local emulator and the deployed function? Is there any configuration that I might be missing for deployment? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help!